# How to return Subscription ID from MemberPress

Tags: php, wordpress, memberpress

I'm attempting to implement AWIN tracking to my wordpress site. I need to return the subscription ID, and the voucher code used for a transaction.

See Below:

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
'transactionID': "{transactionID}",
'transactionPromoCode': "{transactionPromoCode}",
'event': "awin.dl.ready"
}];
</script>
```

I need to replace "{transactionID}" with the unique string that comes with each sale. I do not know how to do this

I tried firstly doing this:

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
'transactionTotal': "7.99",
'transactionCurrency': "GBP",
'transactionID' = subscr_id ,
'transactionPromoCode' = voucher ,
'event': "awin.dl.ready"
}];
</script>`
```

`
I used subscr_id and voucher as they are whats listed in the memberpress documentation. This however did not work.[see image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGaz9.png) As you can see, each Memberpress transaction has a unique reference number [see image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzIwQ.png)

What I need to do is return the unique ID for the order, into this code provided by the affiliate marketplace

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
'transactionID': "{INSERT CODE HERE}",
'transactionPromoCode': "{transactionPromoCode}",
'event': "awin.dl.ready"
}];
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out?